# Web Scrape from site using python ***educational purpose only

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi as a newbie writing code, I try to do realistic projects.
One of them was to write  some code in order to get data from eshop
I tried at a specific using the code below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from datetime import datetime

# Define the URLs you want to scrape
urls = ["https://www.sklavenitis.gr/mpiskota-sokolates-zacharodi/mpiskota/",
        "https://www.sklavenitis.gr/mpiskota-sokolates-zacharodi/mpiskota/?pg=2",
        "https://www.sklavenitis.gr/mpiskota-sokolates-zacharodi/mpiskota/?pg=3"]

for url in urls:
    # Make a request
    response = requests.get(url)

    # Parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Find all the products on the page
    products = soup.find_all('div', class_='product')

    # Define the file path
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
    filename = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', f'{timestamp}.txt')

    # Write the product information to a file on the desktop
    with open(filename, "a") as f:  # Use 'a' instead of 'w' to append to the file instead of overwriting it
        # Add timestamp header for the first URL
        if url == urls[0]:
            f.write("Time, Product Title, Price, Deleted Price\n")

        # Loop over each product and extract the information
        for product in products:
            product_title = product.find('h4', class_='product__title').text.strip()
            deleted_price = product.find('div', class_='deleted__price').text.strip()
            current_price = product.find('div', class_='price')['data-price']

            # Add timestamp column
            f.write(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}, {product_title}, {current_price}, {deleted_price}\n")

    print(f"Product information from {url} saved to desktop!")
```

but as a result I got only the first product.
In a specific point I managed to get the six first products but I can't find the code....

Thanks in advance

**** Still I want to specify that the code is for personal & educational purpose ONLY!

I wanted all products and values I asked from the urls and I got only one, the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL (when you open developer tools -> network tab and start scolling you should see the Ajax call there):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sklavenitis.gr/mpiskota-sokolates-zacharodi/mpiskota/?$component=Atcom.Sites.Yoda.Components.ProductList.Index&sortby=ByPopularity&pg={page}&endless=true&backwards=true'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0'}

for page in range(1, 4):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page=page), headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    for p in soup.select('.product'):
        print(p.h4.text.strip(), p.select_one('.price').text.strip())
    print()
```

Prints:

```
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Πτι Μπερ Μπισκότα οικογενειακή συσκευασία 3x225gr 2,40 €/τεμ.
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Digestive Μπισκότα με Επικάλυψη Μαύρη Σοκολάτα 200gr 1,83 €/τεμ.
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Πολυδημητριακά Μπισκότα με 4 Δημητριακά & Σοκολάτα 160gr 1,75 €/τεμ.
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Γεμιστά Μπισκότα με Γεύση Σοκολάτα 3x200gr 2,80 €/τεμ.
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Πτι Μπερ Μπισκότα με Επικάλυψη Σοκολάτα Γάλακτος 2x200gr 2,07 €/τεμ.
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Digestive Μπισκότα Χωρίς ζάχαρη 250gr 1,76 €/τεμ.
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Cream Κράκερς Σίκαλης 175gr 1,27 €/τεμ.
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Μιράντα Μπισκότα 30% Λιγότερη ζάχαρη 250gr 1,67 €/τεμ.
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Cream Κράκερς Χωρίς ζάχαρη 165gr 1,35 €/τεμ.
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Πτι Μπερ Μπισκότα Χωρίς προσθήκη ζάχαρης 225gr 1,34 €/τεμ.
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Cream Κράκερς Classic 140gr 1,27 €/τεμ.
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Digestive Μπισκότα με Επικάλυψη Σοκολάτα Γάλακτος 200gr 1,83 €/τεμ.
ΠΑΠΑΔΟΠΟΥΛΟΥ Digestive Μπισκότα 2x250gr 2,74 €/τεμ.
ΑΛΛΑΤΙΝΗ Soft Kings Triple Choco Μπισκότα 180gr 1,49 €/τεμ.

...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  It is very helpfull!  Still, I have 2 questions.    1. Finding the url, could you guide me more? Is something that all page have?   2. The headers line? Where can I find it?    Thanks 4all again!!!!